# Set order status to closed

Tags: order-status, refund

I am programatically doing an invoice refund, and I want to set the order status to closed after the refund has happened.

The refund works, but changing the order status doesn't.

I was kind of hoping that the refund code would set the status to Closed for me, but it doesn't, the status just stays at Processing after the refund.

Here's the refund code:

```
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order);
$creditmemo = $service->prepareInvoiceCreditmemo($invoice);
$creditmemo->register();
$creditmemo->save();
```

I have read that the Complete and Closed statuses shouldn't be set manually, but I do need the order status changed to closed.

Here's what I've tried, none worked for me.

1.

```
$order->addStatusHistoryComment("Refunded.", Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CLOSED);
```

2.

```
$order->setData('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CLOSED);
$order->save();
```

3.

```
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CLOSED)->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get the order status to closed after a refund, by doing 2 things.

1. Calling `$order->save();` after the refund code.
2. Preventing the sales_order_invoice_save_after event from firing twice by adding this to the top of my event method:

   ```
   // prevent this event from firing twice
   if(Mage::registry('sales_order_invoice_save_after_event_triggered'))
   {
       return $this; // this method has already been executed once in this request
   }
   Mage::register('sales_order_invoice_save_after_event_triggered', true);
   ```

Comment: Believe me I tried, it says I have to wait until tomorrow.

Comment: When you can, I meant :)

Answer (score 9):

Order status/state `Closed`/`closed` is a "protected" status/state, which cannot be changed, along with `Complete`/`complete`. This means when you use the method `setState`, it will not work.

This is because in order to have a `Closed` order, you must have a fully invoiced and shipped order fully refunded. It looks like in your case you don't have a full shipment. If you have a full shipment and still not getting to `Closed`, something was done wrong.

In any case, you have two options.

1. Do a full shipment (dummy if necessary). Refund fully and you should get to `Closed` automatically.
2. Go around the restriction by using `setData('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CLOSED)` instead of `setState`.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's a great explanation. Could you explain how to do a dummy shipment though?

Comment: Not to worry about the dummy shipment, I have managed to solve the issue. (I've posted my answer).